# SQL query with CASE in SELECT doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have this part of a larger complex query:

```
SELECT SUM(pir.priceChange) AS CASE 
WHEN (SUM(pir.priceChange) > 0) THEN sellSum 
WHEN (SUM(pir.priceChange) < 0) THEN priceSum 
END
```

Whenever I try to pass it on to MySQL (MyISAM) via PDO, it throws me an exception:

> Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(SELECT  SUM(pir.priceChange) AS CASE WHEN (SUM(pir.priceChange) > 0) THEN sellSu' at line 17

I imagine it has something to do with the fact that I'm trying to use a CASE statement incorrectly. Would really like to know what's exactly wrong, thanks in advance.

EDIT: My full query (edited without any cases):

```
SELECT  pi.id AS id,
pi.type AS type,
pi.parValue AS rating,
pi.duration AS time,
countAmt.amt AS amtSold,
IFNULL(pii.pChange,
0) AS priceTotal,
0) AS costTotal,
IFNULL(pii.selfPrice,
0) AS costPrice,
(IFNULL(pii.sellSum,
0) - IFNULL(pii.selfPrice,
0)) AS profit,
countClose.amtClosed AS amtClosed
FROM salon.paymentInstrument as pi
(SELECT SUM(pir.priceChange) AS pChange,
SUM(pir.costChange) AS cChange,
(IFNULL(pir.priceChange,
0) - IFNULL(pir.costChange,
0)) AS selfPrice,
pii.paymentInstrumentID
FROM salon.paymentInstrumentRegister as pir
JOIN salon.paymentInstrumentItem as pii ON pir.paymentInstrumentItemID = pii.id
WHERE pir.date >= '2014-04-11'
AND pir.date <= '2014-04-25'
GROUP BY pii.paymentInstrumentID 
) as pii
(SELECT pii.paymentInstrumentID,
COUNT(*) AS amtClosed
FROM salon.paymentInstrumentItem as pii
WHERE pii.annulTime >= 2014-04-11
AND pii.annulTime <= 2014-04-25
AND pii.status <> "active"
GROUP BY pii.paymentInstrumentID 
) as countClose
(SELECT pii.paymentInstrumentID,
COUNT(*) AS amt
FROM salon.paymentInstrumentItem as pii
WHERE pii.startTime >= 2014-04-11
AND pii.startTime <= 2014-04-25
GROUP BY pii.paymentInstrumentID 
) as countAmt
```

Sorry for improper formatting, it's generated dynamically with PHP. I have a feeling i'm making a mistake somewhere else in the query.

Comment: With `AS` you declare an alias.

Comment: Yeah, I want to change the alias based on the value.

Comment: How would you use the results of the query if the alias is unknown to you?

Comment: The result is later passed on to the layer of logic which either gets a null or a value and makes an object out of the selection. :)

Comment: Let me post the full query though, may be it will help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this way:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN SUM(pir.priceChange)>0 THEN SUM(pir.priceChange) END as SumPrice,
       CASE WHEN SUM(pir.priceChange)<0 THEN SUM(pir.priceChange) END as priceSum
FROM TableName
```

An example in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/aa09ab/1).

Comment: I'm looking at this, but cannot tell what the difference is between the case statements.

Comment: this wont get compiled

Comment: @paqogomez: Neither your suggestion or answer works.

Comment: Hm, your SQL fiddle indeed works yet i can't make it work like that. Could it be that the aggregate function SUM is interfering?

Comment: @Ravinder, you are correct, Raging has it right here.  I deleted my answer.  When OP says `which either gets a null or a value and makes an object out of the selection` that fits what Raging is doing. (+1)

Comment: Actually, OP should look for a *pivot* result as answered by @RagingBull. Unless which, selective aliases wont work.

Comment: I posted a full query, I probably made a mistake somewhere else.

Comment: @nainy: As far as I know, you can't change the alias name of a single column unless you use dynamic sql. For such a huge query you are trying, dynamic sql would not be a good idea.

Comment: I'm not a fan of complex queries myself, but right now I just don't have a choice. I kind of tried altering it so that the case statement isn't present anymore but it still doesn't work and throws an exception in that same place so I'm guessing I need to look the other way.

Comment: @nainy: Can't you remove the `null` column in php?

Comment: I update the query in the OP as it goes without any cases. And yeah I can of course, I just need the query to work and it doesn't :)

Comment: @nainy: You are missing an IFNULL after `IFNULL(pii.pChange, 0) AS priceTotal,`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT CASE 
WHEN (SUM(pir.priceChange) > 0) THEN sellSum 
WHEN (SUM(pir.priceChange) < 0) THEN priceSum 
END
```